# Как организовать рендеринг SPA React приложения на сервере используя PHP V8js?

Tags: php, reactjs

Имеется уже готовое SPA приложение на React. Но возник вопрос серверного рендеринга. Это связано с SEO. Как можно организовать этот самый серверный рендеринг уже готового react-приложения используя PHP и расширение V8js? Где посмотреть примеры кода? Надо что б, например, bundle.js, который подключается к index.html выполнился на сервере и выдал клиенту уже наполненную контентом страницу.

Comment: http://www.phpied.com/server-side-react-with-php-part-2/

Comment: я так же начинал делать, но в итоге перешёл на node.js - для фронта и API на php

Comment: @xFloooo ок, а как тогда организовать архитектурно связку react-приложения, nodejs и php? Есть статья поясняющая?

Comment: через api, монжо graphQL например накрутить

Answer (score 0):

это не прямой ответ, но поскольку вопрос может быть актуален для многих, поскольку проблемы сео касаются всех кто делает одностраничное (SPA) приложение, опишу возможное направление для получения желаемого результата. для решения по пути который в вопросе есть много статей о создании так называемого изоморфного приложения (например давняя, но понятно описывающая, которая уже была приведена в качестве примера на этом ресурсе https://habr.com/ru/post/259625/), которое одновременно выполняется на сервере и в браузере. статей достаточно немало и если исчезнет одна, появятся другие, которые можно именно по этому наименованию и найти. кода много и приводить сюда нет смысла. при этом сразу отдается практически готовый html код для сео и скрипт для действий пользователя. на сервере можно так же все сделать например на той же ноде (Express), что упростит построение дублирующего кода. при этом не важно как организован бэкенд. главное чтобы обе эти части получали данные из одного места одинаково и выдавали в конечном итоге одно и тоже. сам bundle.js будет при этом выполняться на клиенте, а готовый html для поискового робота отдаст сервер например на упомянутом Express.
если же посмотреть на конечную цель этой затеи то, возможно, больше устроит просто подстраивание под задачу или как временное решение -  есть сервисы, которые предлагают немного бесплатно, а если большой трафик то за деньги осуществлять рендеринг у себя, либо и это можно сделать на своем сервере, если он выделенный, при этом все что есть проходит через этот рендер и робот и клиент получают готовый html. я в свое время от этой идеи отказался, но информировать о ней обязан.